# a simple question about Quantifiers

Tags: logic, quantifiers

first of all it's not an exam sheet or some kinda stuff.  I'm just preparing myself about quantifiers.

i couldn't find similar task to this one so had to ask here.

---

Let '$x \mathrel{\heartsuit} y$' stand for 'x loves y'. Rewrite the sentence 'Someone loves everyone' using quantifiers in two different ways.

Comment: Please use MathJax mark-up. I've fixed it for you.

Comment: Unfortunately, the English language sentence you wrote is ambiguous.  It could mean "there is someone, (call him bob), and everyone is loved by bob", or it could mean "everyone is loved by someone (not necessarily the same person)".  That's the problem with these "convert into formal language" problems.....if English was precise enough, we'd have a lot less reason to use formal language.

Comment: A comedic example is when the announcer says "every 11 seconds someone in New York city gets robbed.  Tonight, we have brought him here."

Answer (score 2):

I can only think of one way:
$$\exists x \forall y:x \heartsuit y$$

Comment: You could change the quantifiers to get: $\neg\forall x \exists y:\neg x \heartsuit y$

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the second interpretation would be something along the lines of: there is someone for eveyone' ... So for evryone there is someone who loves them. So switch the quatifiers for the second reading?